# C# how i can have base classes?

Tags: c#, class

i have a DLL that is the base for some software and i need to use this in a software but i need to add some vars.

This is the Element class that i have in the DLL

```
public abstract class Element
{
    public PointF pStart = new PointF();
    public PointF pEnd = new PointF();

    public Element()
    {}

    public Element(Element source)
    {
        if (source != null)
        {
            pStart = source.pStart;
            pEnd = source.pEnd;
        }
    }

    public abstract void createSteps();
}
```

And this is a derived class from Element, always in the DLL

```
public class ElementLine : Element
{

    public ElementLine()
    {}

    public ElementLine(ElementLine source): base(source)
    {}

    public override void createSteps()
    {
        Code for calculate steps....
    }
}
```

Now i need to add a IntPtr to those class so in my software i created those classes:

Class Element that have ad base class the DLL Element Class

```
abstract class Element : BASECLASS.Element
{
    IntPtr entIntPtr;

    public IntPtr EntIntPtr
    {
        get => this.entIntPtr;
        set
        {
            this.entIntPtr = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i have the problem because i need to add a class ElementLine that have the createSteps function from the BASECLASS.ElementLine but it need to be a derived from Element too. But if i use as base class Element i don' have the createSteps function. If i use BASECLASS.ElementLine i can't convert a Element to a ElementLine.

So the 2 situation are:

The problem with this is that i can't convert this to Element, because it's not the base class

```
class ElementLine : BASECLASS.ElementLine
{
    IntPtr entIntPtr;

    public PointF PStart
    {
        get => this.pStart;
        set
        {
            this.pStart = value;
        }
    }

    public PointF PEnd
    {
        get => this.pEnd;
        set
        {
            this.pEnd = value;
        }
    }

    public IntPtr EntIntPtr
    {
        get => this.entIntPtr;
        set
        {
            this.entIntPtr = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here i can convert ElementLine to Element but i don't have the BASECLASS.ElementLine method createSteps(). So the only way to let this work is copy the code from BASECLASS.ElementLine here. But i don't like

```
class ElementLine : Element
{
    IntPtr entIntPtr;

    public PointF PStart
    {
        get => this.pStart;
        set
        {
            this.pStart = value;
        }
    }

    public PointF PEnd
    {
        get => this.pEnd;
        set
        {
            this.pEnd = value;
        }
    }

    public override void createSteps()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I hope everything is well explained and in case you have any doubts do not hesitate to contact me

**UPDATE:**

For understand better how i need to use it here is another part. Sorry mb i need to post it before.

This is the container of Elements (there are more types of Element, ElementLine, ElementArc, ecc...) in the DLL

```
public class Container
{
    public virtual List<Element> elements { get; set; } = new List<Element>();
}
```

In my software i replace it with the  newone because i nee to replace the elements type from the old Element to the new Element with the new IntPtr param

```
public class Container : BASECLASS.Container
{
    new public List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
}
```

The problem is that if for example i need to execute a foreach loop if i have the ***ElementLine : BASECLASS.ElementLine*** i can't do the foreach

```
foreach (Element element in container.elements)
        {
            if(element is ElementLine)
            {
                 ElementLine line = element as ElementLine;
            }
        }
```

Here i get an error because the base class of ElementLine is not Element but BASECLASS.ElementLine

If i put ***ElementLine : Element*** i can execute the foreach but i can't use the createSteps() method because every Element have his own alghoritm for calculate steps so i need to have it abstact on Element and implement it on every Element type

At the end the result need to be :
class Element : BASECLASS.Element
class ElementLine : Element

so ElementLine need to have all the vars inside BASECLASS.Element and Element (and that's ok) but at the same time in the ElementLine createSteps() method i want to execute the same code inside BASECLASS.ElementLine createSteps()

Comment: Can you make ElementLine inherit from your new base class instead? Just change it?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest having the classes in your program *encapsulate* the related type in the DLL, rather than *inherit* from them. What you're asking for doesn't exist and cannot be made to work without modifying the original base class.

Comment: "Composition over Inheritance" is a term, you'll likely hear in that context.

Comment: *i need to add a IntPtr to those class* - so your cour code can use it, or in the hopes that the DLL code will use it? (It won't)

Comment: Why is Element a class in the first place? It looks perfectly to be just an interface.

Comment: You should be using struct for the data that you are reading/writing to dll and using Marshal techniques for importing/exporting the struct from/to dll.  Your new variables can be added to end of struct.

Comment: @jdweng Are you implying the DLL is accessed via P/Invoke?

Comment: **The problem with this is that i can't convert this to Element, because it's not the base class**, wait, isnt `BASECLASS.ElementLine` inherits `BASECLASS.Element`? who will use the `IntPtr` thing? if its your own code, you can make that field contractually "the same" through interface.

Comment: What will those properties do? (I can see that they simply parrot fields that are already public; they don't appear to add anything?)

Comment: *class ElementLine : BASECLASS.ElementLine* - I think it'd be clearer if you left their names alone and called your class MyElementLine (or whatever), then you could speak more plainly about what XElementX is-a OtherXElementX

Comment: (The bit I'm particularly lost on is where you say "I can't convert ElementLine to Element" - I thought anything is-a Element, regardles of whether you inherit Element or ElementLine)

Comment: In c#, you can only cast a smaller object to a larger object (not larger to smaller) since going from large to small it takes less memory.  So you can only cast a base class to an inherited class and not an inherited class to a base class.  It is like trying to take a large box and put into a smaller box, but you can put a small box into a larger box.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen do you mean to do something like: 'class ElementLine : BASECLASS.ElementLine'  ? If yes i can't do it beacuse if i do it i lose the IntPtr property and i can't convert ElementLine to Element because it's not his base class

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i can edit the DLL it's mine so i can change the BASECLASS

Comment: @CaiusJard i explained it better (i hope) in the Update

Comment: @Ralf if i put Element as interface i can use it like in the Update? i've tried change the type to interface but i get error on createSteps()

Comment: *i replace it with the newone because i nee to replace the elements type from the old Element to the new Element with the new IntPtr param* - it won't work

Comment: You said you can edit the DLL. If you want everything to have an IntPtr, including the DLL classes, edit the DLL and add it

Comment: *At the end the result need to be : class Element : BASECLASS.Element class ElementLine : Element* - again, you can't do it. The DLL's ElementLine inherits the DLL's Element. You cannot declare a new class called Element, that inherits the DLL's Element, and expect the DLL's ElementLine to switch to using your new Element

Comment: Everything has a `createSteps`, because the original base Element does. ElementLine's createStpes will never use, or need to use, the IntPtr youre trying to add in your third level class.. If you jsut want your new class to amke use of the IntPtr, just inherit ElementLine, add an IntPtr in your class, override createSteps again and use the IntPtr and leave the DLLs classes alone. If you want new behavior, make an instance of your new third-level descendant MyElementLine that uses IntPtr in its createSteps, and load it into the `List<Element>` - youre permitted to do this, heritably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tries on how i could do it the most beautiful way that i've found is to instantiate a base element inside the class and add the needed values like that:

```
public class ElementLine : Element
{
    IntPtr EntIntPtr;
    BASECLASS.ElementLine line;

    public ElementLine()
    {}

    public ElementLine(ElementLine source): base(source)
    {}
}
```

In this way i can use the createSteps function on the DLL (line.createSteps()), i can add values to the class like the IntPtr and my ElementLine is a derived class of Element so i can convert ElementLine to Element

Answer (score 0):

That you need is use interfaces and cast to each when you need. Define this interface:

```
public interface IIntPtr
{
    IntPtr EntIntPtr { get; set; }
}
```

Create the classes:

```
public class Element2 : Element, IIntPtr
{
}

public class ElementLine2 : ElementLine, IIntPtr
{
}
```

As they implements IIntPtr, you must Add that property in both classes.

Now, you can invoke createSteps in Element2 and ElementLine2 as you are doing now. And, if you need access to EntIntPtr, you only need do a casting:

```
foreach (Element element in container.elements)
{
   // All are Element, so you can invoke this without any casting
   element.createSteps();

   var intPtr = element as IIntPtr;
   if (intPtr != null)
   {
      // Use intPtr.EntIntPtr
   }
}
```